# Sequentially multiply matrices from a list by a vector at time t-1 (recursively)

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion, matrix-multiplication, projection-matrix

I am trying to multiply a list of matrices, in the order they appear within the list starting with matrix 1, by an initial vector and then recursively; so matrix 2 from the list multiplied by that resulting vector. I have tried various iteration of `lapply` and `map` but am unable to project forward and perform this recursively. More explicitly: `A[[1]] % * % allYears[,1]`, then `A[[2]] % * % allYears[,2],.....,A[[4]] % * % allYears[,4]` which produces the final 5th column in `"allYears"`. Below is the sample code with the known error in the for loop at `A[[i]]` indexing as `i` is not explicitly referenced.

```
A <- lapply(1:4, function(x)  # construct list of matrices
  matrix(c(0, 0, 10, 
           rbeta(1, 5, 4), 0, 0, 
           0, rbeta(1, 10, 2), 0), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, ))

n <- c(1000, 100, 10)  # initial vector of abundances

nYears <- 4  # define the number of years to project over

allYears <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=nYears+1)  # build a storage array for all abundances

allYears[, 1] <- n  # set the year 0 abundance   

for (t in 1:(nYears + 1)) {   # loop through all years
  allYears[, t] <- A[[i]] %*% allYears[, t - 1]
}
```

Comment: I have corrected to nYears +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, perhaps we need to loop over the sequence - i.e. length of `A` is `4`, whereas the number of columns of 'allYears' is 5. Create an index from 2 to `ncol` of 'allYears', then loop over the sequence of that index, extract the corresponding element of 'A' based on the sequence whereas we get the `allYears` previous column

```
i1 <- 2:(nYears + 1)
 for(t in seq_along(i1)) {
    allYears[,i1[t]] <-  A[[t]] %*% allYears[,i1[t]-1]
 
 }
```

-output

```
> allYears
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1000 100.00000 817.24277 2081.08322  333.6702
[2,]  100 261.46150  55.44237  423.22095 1244.6680
[3,]   10  81.72428 208.10832   33.36702  355.5175
```

Comment: that would be it, thank you kindly.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right? `A[[1]] %*% n` is (100, 569, 78) ...

Comment: @BenBolker There was no `set.seed` in OP's example.  So, the values you got may be different

Comment: aha.  Thanks  ....

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, possibly too clever, solution:

Construct a list of (`A[[1]]`, `A[[1]] %*% A[[2]]`, ... )

```r
Alist <- Reduce("%*%", A, accumulate=TRUE)
```

Multiply each of these by the initial value

```r
vlist <- lapply(Alist, "%*%", n)
```

Combine:

```r
do.call(cbind, vlist)
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 100.00000 856.66558 4864.20044  486.420
[2,] 569.23739  56.92374  543.02451 3307.690
[3,]  78.55101 553.62548   55.36255  445.619
```

@MikaelJagan points out that this can be done in fewer steps:

```r
do.call(cbind, 
        rev(Reduce("%*%", rev(A), init = n, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE)))
```

or (in recent versions of R)

```r
(A
  |> rev()
  |> Reduce(f = "%*%", init = n, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE)
  |> rev()
  |> do.call(what = cbind)
)
```

(The last step could be replaced by `|> unlist() |> matrix(nrow = length(n))`.)

Comment: Maybe you want `matrix(unlist(Reduce("%*%", A, init = n, accumulate = TRUE)), nrow = length(n))`.

Comment: You're too fast for me!

Comment: I have a feeling I've made a mistake, though...

Comment: I think I've got it now... I've written this comment three times... By default, `Reduce` does `init %*% A[[i]]`. In order to get what we want, we need to pass `right = TRUE` _and_ reverse the order of the input and output. Hence `matrix(unlist(rev(Reduce("%*%", rev(A), init = n, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE))), nrow = length(n))`.